# How to query BigQuery tables with suffixes using R as done in console/ other languages (e.g. python)?

Tags: python, r, google-bigquery

Currently I am using `bigrquery` package for querying tables from bigquery for its simplicity & straightforward nature. Which although works fine for simple queries like:
`SELECT * FROM project_salsa_101.dashboards.product_20190501`, it struggles when I try to access date-partitioned tables as: `SELECT * FROM project_salsa_101.dashboards.product_*`. As when I run:

```
project_id <- "project_salsa_101" 

#query
sql_string <- "SELECT * FROM `project_salsa_101.dashboards.product_*`
LIMIT 10000000"

#Execute the query and storing the result
query_results <- query_exec(sql_string, project = project_id, useLegacySql = FALSE)
query_results
```

It throws following error:

```
Error: Invalid table name: `project_salsa_101.dashboards.product_*`
[Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)]. [invalid] 
Traceback:

1. query_exec(sql_string, project = project_id, useLegacySql = FALSE)
2. run_query_job(query = query, project = project, destination_table = destination_table, 
 .     default_dataset = default_dataset, create_disposition = create_disposition, 
 .     write_disposition = write_disposition, use_legacy_sql = use_legacy_sql, 
 .     quiet = quiet, ...)
3. wait_for(job, quiet = quiet)
4. signal_reason(err$reason, err$message)
5. rlang::abort(message, class = paste0("bigrquery_", reason))
6. signal_abort(cnd)
```

Setting parameter: `useLegacySql= TRUE` does not help either.

Query is fine in itself as it runs flawlessly in console when I try to run it in python as:

```
from datetime import datetime
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'credentials.json')
project_id = 'project_salsa_101'
client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)
query_job = client.query("""
SELECT * FROM `project_salsa_101.dashboards.product_*`
LIMIT 10000000""")
results = query_job.result()
```

### EDIT 1:

Query makes it to the BigQuery and I can see it submitted there under Query history. It says query failed over there as well. And the same error message is listed there:

```
Error: Invalid table name: `project_salsa_101.dashboards.product_*`
[Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)]. [invalid]
```

Interestingly enough, when I copy the query from the same errored job history and paste the query into console, it runs perfectly!

Comment: can you look at the job history in bq and see if the query made it and if it did what the query that was submitted was?

Comment: Yupp @DanielZagales I have added additional info regarding that